# viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator return wrong size in simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode6, size-classes

Hi Iam using this code to support splitViewController on iPhone 6:

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id <UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    self.forcedTraitCollection = nil;
    if (size.height == 320.0 || size.width == 320.0)
    {
        self.forcedTraitCollection = nil;
    }
    else
    {
        self.forcedTraitCollection = [UITraitCollection traitCollectionWithHorizontalSizeClass:UIUserInterfaceSizeClassRegular];
    }

    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
}
```

The problem is that the Size returned is wrong - it returns CGSize(320,568) for all simulators.
+n it returns the the width as the height and vice versa.

Thanks

Comment: Did you find problem, I met the same issue.

Comment: This still seems to be a problem. This radar pretty clearly describes the issue I'm having https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwio0oPC6uTgAhXJVt8KHRRaCkAQFjAAegQIChAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fopenradar.appspot.com%2F22885931&usg=AOvVaw3g_SKKrdDRRc8jGh5nXSmi

Answer (score 2):

I'm getting the correct sizes for the different device simulators, but the x and y seem to be flipped when in landscape mode.  I used this hack to correct it:

```
let mainScreen = UIScreen.mainScreen()
let screenSize = mainScreen.applicationFrame // CGRect screen bounds
var width = size.width
if screenSize.width == size.width {
    // size must be wrong or flipped
    width = size.height
}
```